# What is the meaning of "serving html files from a web server, and not open using the file:// protocol" while testing TensorFlow.js on local machine?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, tensorflow.js

I'm trying COCO-SSD Object detection model from TensorFlow.js on the local machine and it's not working as expected as shown on Codepen, even though code is exactly the same. In the Google Codelabs, there is a caution message and I'm pasting it here as-it-is.

> Caution: If you are running locally, instead of another site like
> Codepen.io or similar, ensure you are serving the files from a web
> server and not just double clicking the index.html to open using the
> file:// protocol.

Link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-object-detection#3

I'm opening it as an html file with file:// protocol. I don't understand what is meant by "serving html files from web server" here. I'm also familiar with Nodejs, so please feel free to guide me if it has something to do with that here. Thank you.

Comment: It's saying not to open directly as an HTML file. You need to have a local web server running.

Comment: Not really, you can setup any webserver locally and have it load that file. It can be done with Node or WAMP for example. Are you getting an errors?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rylee. I did it and it's working as expected now.